# Как получить url ЧПУ?

Tags: php, чпу

Получаю url страницы на которой нахожусь при помощи следующей функции:

```
function getUrl() {
    $url  = @( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] :  'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $url .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
    $url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    return $url;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузерной строке ссылка с ЧПУ, ниже без чпу, которая возвращает мне вышеприведённая функция

Но она определяет url без чпу, как достать url страницы на которой я нахожусь уже с ЧПУ?

Comment: если "она определяет url без чпу" то ЧПУ реализовано неправильно. в $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] должен быть чпу запрос

Comment: @Ипатьев это стандартный ЧПУ в движке shopscript, роботы его воспринимают нормально. Переделывать с нуля ЧПУ как-то не разумно) может есть какие костыли для решения проблемы?

Comment: Причем здесь роботы? Они тебе в код что ли лазят? Если криворукие авторы этого скрипта переписывают REQUEST_URI, попробуй поискать в других элементах $_SERVER.